# Missing play-{version}.jar error

Tags: java, playframework

I have follow the README, by git clone the play1.git and move play1 to /opt directory,
and I have add it to PATH.   [play1 README](https://github.com/playframework/play1)

- the first problem I encounter was missing 'version' file in `/opt/play1/framework/src/play`, so I touched one as to run play command.
- after all, I make a new play app by `play new test` and run `play run test`, shows these errors:

> ```
> Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /opt/play1/framework/play-.jar
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> agent library failed to init: instrument
> ```

can anybody tell me, what happened?

Comment: Do you realise that's quite an old version of Play?

Comment: @GregKopff I guese I am using play-1.2.7, is it having any terrible bug?

Comment: No, it's simply if this was something _new_ you were doing, I'd suggest looking at `Play 2.x` instead.

Answer (score 0):

according to this [page](http://spinscale.github.io/play-introduction.html), figure 55, 
I have to **ant** after clone from github.

another problem found when using ant to build Docviewer module， modify modules/docviewer/build.xml if needed.